# External Identity in Azure AD and B2X user flows

Tags: azure-active-directory, powerapps

I am trying to implement an Azure AD B2X in my PowerApps website. So that external users can sign up and create a new account but it doesn't have the "create one" option

[Azure Active Directory Sign In without create one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBo7g.jpg)

I have been trying to follow this tutorial here by making sure the "Enable guest self-service sign up via user flows" is set to yes, but still I cannot see the "create one" option

https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/external-identity-in-azure-ad-and-b2x-user-flows-e5f7db70616c

I am sure there is wrong setup somewhere. Can someone please help me where else I should look ?

Thank you so much for your help.

[Enable guest self-service sign up via user flows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twizJ.png)

Here is my website

https://austroads.powerappsportals.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because that you didn't configure the app registration (client id is `bd03a7aa-448a-482a-b5ea-f0bcdf056bb6`) under "Applications".

[image]

Please add it into the B2X user flow.